# Dynamics CRM REST OAuth Authentication Response 403 - The user is not a member of the organization

Tags: java, rest, authentication, oauth, dynamics-crm

I am attempting to make a request to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM REST API.
I am receiving a 403 response with message "The user is not a member of the organization."
Could anyone advise where I am going wrong?

The Java Code I am using (I have removed ids/hostnames etc.):

```
public class CRMTesting {

    private static String TENANT_ID = "<tenant-id>";
    private static String POST_URL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + TENANT_ID + "/oauth2/token";
    private static String CLIENT_ID = "<client-id>";
    private static String CLIENT_SECRET = "<client-secret>";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String token = getToken();
        getAccounts(token);
    }

    public static String getAccounts(String token) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://<company>.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/accounts?$select=name&$top=3");
        httpGet.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
        httpGet.setHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
        httpGet.setHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        System.out.println("Response Status Code... " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        reader.close();
        httpClient.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());

        // Extract the token from the json response
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(response.toString());

        return actualObj.get("access_token").asText();

    }

    public static String getToken() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        // create headers

        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(POST_URL);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("resource", "https://<company>.crm4.dynamics.com"));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id", CLIENT_ID));
        nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret", CLIENT_SECRET));
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

        CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent()));

        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        reader.close();
        httpClient.close();

        System.out.println(response.toString());

        // Extract the token from the json response
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonNode actualObj = mapper.readTree(response.toString());

        return actualObj.get("access_token").asText();

    }

}
```

The 403 response:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":"3599","ext_expires_in":"3599","expires_on":"1698847590","not_before":"1698843690","resource":"https://<company>.crm4.dynamics.com","access_token":"<access-token>"}
Response Status Code... 403
{"error":{"code":"0x80072560","message":"The user is not a member of the organization."}}
```

I have tried many things such as adding a "scope" parameter in the token request.. using a different POST url "/oauth2/v2.0/token".. using java.net.HttpURLConnection rather than apache CloseableHttpClient.. etc. however I am yet to find a solution.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Have you added that client id to CRM as an app user? and given it security roles?

Comment: @jasonscript no I haven't. Would you be able to point me to an article? Or give any hints? Do I just create a User in CRM with the username the same as the client  I'd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got an Application User in Azure, with a Tenant Id and a Client ID, you have to add that user to your CRM instance, and then give it security roles

- Navigate to https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/environments
- Select your environment
- Navigate to Users
- Navigate to App Users
- Add an App User

This will take you through the process of adding your Application User to a Business Unit, and giving it some security roles.

Once you've done that, try your code again

Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/power-platform/admin/manage-application-users?WT.mc_id=ppac_inproduct_settings